# Cooperating applications on heroku

Tags: heroku

I plan to have two physical applications on heroku that cooperate as one logical application.  One app is written in Grails, the other is node.js.

I have a question on the technical feasibility of this on heroku:

1. Can these applications share the same postgres database?  (or will
   heroku prevent this?)

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267058/354577) ask [only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120633/248627) one question per question. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question based on info found on the Heroku development site.

To share a database (after it's been "Added On" to the first application.

```
 heroku addons:attach app1::DATABASE --app app2
```

Where app1 is the Heroku application that created the database and app2 is the Heroku application with which to watch it.